# change localhost sendmail sender

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I've been all this morning trying to set up sendmail on my dev machine, it's almost done but 
every time I try to send an email from my localhost:

```
"test nagios email" | /usr/bin/mail -a "From:ubuntu@nagios.website.net" -s "Test" critcial@website.com
```

I get:

```
send-mail: RCPT TO:<critcial@website.com> (504 5.5.2 <vivo@vivo-pc>: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address)
Can't send mail: sendmail process failed with error code 1
```

I've tried several things,
like

- changing my user `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` to a `valid_sender.com`
- changing `/etc/mailname`
- changing the MASQUERADE_AS in `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` to `valid_sender.com`
- etc...

But nothing, I'm unable to achieve it :/

Comment: Do you have the file `/etc/postfix/main.cf`?

Comment: no, I didn't install it, I'm using only sendmail (afaik), and no, the file does not exist

Comment: What have been reported in the log file?

Answer (score 0):

Well... nothing worked for me until I installed `postfix`. Once I did it stopped ignoring all what I tried before.